# Create new specified folder with AS3 and AIR

Tags: actionscript-3, air, directory-structure

I am relatively new to the AIR world and need some help (on Windows 7 operating system). I tried searching for help, but I am dumbfounded as what to do. My knowledge of ActionScript 3 is fundamental and I am completely new to working with Adobe AIR. I will keep this thread short and not go into great detail about the rest of my application.

Any help is appreciated, I am completely lost.

Steps:

1. The user runs my Adobe Air application. 
   (and it does open, just the buttons don't work yet)
2. User clicks the "Save As" button and is prompted with a window to choose the desired directory.
3. After they choose the directory the directory path is stored in a String variable.
4. Then the user clicks the "OK" button. This will grab the path directory variable and create a new folder. The folder will have the name from a variable string.

Comment: You should take a look at the FileReference class and see if's helpful. From your question, I'm not sure what you're trying to save though. http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/FileReference.html

Comment: @CristinaGeorgescu You should actually use the `File` class when using AIR, not `FileReference`. It gives you far more control.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a sample code for selecting a directory

```
    protected function browseBtn_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
    {
        var browseFile:File = FileUtils.documentsDirectory();
        browseFile.addEventListener(Event.SELECT, fileSelected);
        browseFile.browseForDirectory("Select Local Folder");
        function fileSelected(e:Event):void {
            browseFile.removeEventListener(Event.SELECT, fileSelected);
            if(localDirPath.text != browseFile.nativePath){
                localDirPath.text = browseFile.nativePath;
                changed=true;
            }

        }
    }
```

this is a sample, localDirPath is a `TextInput` where I display the selected path, changed is a flag,  so you use the File class in AIR for Desktop.Check the documentation [`File Class Reference`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/File.html) check the methods that contain "browse" like `browseForOpen`, `browseForSave`, `createDirectory`